# return to form on occurance of exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, return, break

a **Win form application** in **VS 2010** using **C#** and **web service** as **back end**

when any type of **exception occurs** how to return to window-form

exception occurs in a function which is in another class,what i want is just jump out of everything without executing anything , after occurrence of exception

Comment: What do you mean by "return to window-form"?

Comment: return to the form where we are doing some stuff and gets exception

Comment: Exception already does something similar to what you described, i.e. 'jumps out of everything'. Since you posted your question, I believe you want to do something else. What exactly? Do you want to swallow the exception? Do some kind of a rollback on whatever the application has been doing? We need a proper description of your problem and some code too.

Comment: when i debug application it takes me to the visual studio ..
shall i throw exception ex or not ?

Comment: If you're taken back to VS, then the exception is already thrown somewhere in your code due to an error of some kind. Did you mean 'catch exception ex'?

Comment: user will put mobile no. in text box and if some exception occurs then how can i just show a message box saying "ERROR OCCURED"
execption occurs in a function which is in a class , so how can i skip the flow of execution and compiler do not read anything after exception

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't catch the exception anywhere, except in your form....

```
void FunctionInForm()  
{
    try  
    {  
        LogicLayer.DoStuff(); //This function and any function it calls should not handle exceptions
    }  
    catch  
    {  
      //an exception occured, and you are back in your form
    }  
}
```